# MVVM Switching Between Views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF so bear with me. I have a WinForms Application that I am trying to redo in WPF. In my current WinForms Application, I stick all my Controls into one Form, and hide/show them based on what buttons are hit, as well as making use of a second form.

My goal: Create different views to switch between smoothly based on what button is hit, instead of hiding Controls or making separate Forms and then hiding those.

I currently have a MainWindow view (My initial launch window), where with a button, I switch to my CreateAccount view. What I am having issues with is, how can I make my button in my CreateAccount go "back" to my MainWindow?

My end goal is to be able to switch between 4 views based off Button clicks.

Here is my MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="MusicPlayer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.Views"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.ViewModels"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="CreateAccountTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:CreateAccountViewModel}">
            <Views:CreateAccountView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="61" Width="68" Click="CreateAccountView_Clicked"/>
        <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,284,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using MusicPlayer.ViewModels;

namespace MusicPlayer {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnClosed(e);

            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        } //end of onClosed

        private void CreateAccountView_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            DataContext = new CreateAccountViewModel();
        } //end of CreateAccountView_Clicked
    }
}
```

And here is my CreateAccount.xaml

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MusicPlayer.Views.CreateAccountView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.Views"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="276,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="59" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my CreateAccountView.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using MusicPlayer.ViewModels;

namespace MusicPlayer.Views {
    public partial class CreateAccountView : UserControl {
        //public static readonly DependencyProperty TestMeDependency = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(CreateAccountView));

        public CreateAccountView() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Current Structure of my Project]

Comment: I recommend viewmodel first. Simple example: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your current attempt is on the right track. The main issue with the code you posted is that the `CreateAccountView.Button_Click()` handler doesn't have access to the `DataContext` property it should be setting:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

This `DataContext` property belongs to the `CreateAccountView` user control. However, this is not the controlling context for what's being displayed. So changing the value of that `DataContext` property doesn't have any useful effect. (Indeed, a user control should not set its own `DataContext` property at all, because doing so discards whatever context the client code using that user control had set.)

There's not enough context to know exactly what *the* best way for you to do this would be. I don't think it would be possible to provide enough context here on Stack Overflow. The overall architecture will depend on too many little details about your program. But, one way to approach this which I think is a good one would be this:

- Create a "main" view model that governs the overall behavior of the app
- Create individual view models that relate to different states of the UI
- Have the main view model configure the individual view models to switch the current view model as appropriate, given the user input (e.g. clicking buttons)

Translating that into code, looks something like this…

First, the view models:

```cs
class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private object _currentViewModel;
    public object CurrentViewModel
    {
        get => _currentViewModel;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _currentViewModel, value);
    }

    private readonly HomeViewModel _homeViewModel;
    private readonly Sub1ViewModel _sub1ViewModel;
    private readonly Sub2ViewModel _sub2ViewModel;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _sub1ViewModel = new Sub1ViewModel
        {
            BackCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => CurrentViewModel = _homeViewModel)
        };

        _sub2ViewModel = new Sub2ViewModel
        {
            BackCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => CurrentViewModel = _homeViewModel)
        };

        _homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel
        {
            ShowSub1Command = new DelegateCommand(() => CurrentViewModel = _sub1ViewModel),
            ShowSub2Command = new DelegateCommand(() => CurrentViewModel = _sub2ViewModel)
        };

        CurrentViewModel = _homeViewModel;
    }
}

class HomeViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private ICommand _showSub1Command;
    public ICommand ShowSub1Command
    {
        get => _showSub1Command;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _showSub1Command, value);
    }

    private ICommand _showSub2Command;
    public ICommand ShowSub2Command
    {
        get => _showSub2Command;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _showSub2Command, value);
    }
}

class Sub1ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private ICommand _backCommand;
    public ICommand BackCommand
    {
        get => _backCommand;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _backCommand, value);
    }
}

class Sub2ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private ICommand _backCommand;
    public ICommand BackCommand
    {
        get => _backCommand;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _backCommand, value);
    }
}
```

Of course, these view models contain *only* the implementation details needed to handle the UI switching. In your program, each would also include the stuff specific to each view state that you need.

In my little sample, the "home" view contains a couple of buttons, used to select the individual sub-views available:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.HomeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Home: "/>
    <Button Content="Sub1" Command="{Binding ShowSub1Command}"/>
    <Button Content="Sub2" Command="{Binding ShowSub2Command}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The sub views just contain the button required to go back to the home view:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Sub1View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Sub1 View: "/>
    <Button Content="Back" Command="{Binding BackCommand}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Sub2View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Sub2 View: "/>
    <Button Content="Back" Command="{Binding BackCommand}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Finally, the main window sets the main view model, and declares templates to use for each of the specific sub views:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:HomeViewModel}">
      <l:HomeView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:Sub1ViewModel}">
      <l:Sub1View/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:Sub2ViewModel}">
      <l:Sub2View/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Importantly, you'll see that *none* of the view objects include any code-behind. It's not necessary when you approach the problem this way, at least not for the purpose of controlling basic behaviors in the code. (You may still wind up with code-behind for view objects, but this will usually only be for the purpose of implementing specific **user-interface** behaviors unique to that view object, not for dealing with the view model state.)

Using this approach, you let WPF do as much of the heavy-lifting as possible. It also decouples all of the view model objects from each other. There's a clear hierarchy: only the top-level "main" view model even knows about the other view models. This allows the sub-view models ("home", "sub1", and "sub2") to be reused as necessary in other scenarios without any modification or special-case handling within them.

Here are the helper classes I used above:

```cs
class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

```cs
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

#pragma warning disable 67
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
#pragma warning restore

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute();
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Peter solution. I have something similar idea about the approach. The  main problem is you are trying to add a MainViewModel datacontext from inside the user control and its is creating a new context every time you load a child control. Best idea is to have a MainViewModel and child view model as it was mentioned in above solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the explanation!